# Add pop up window to macro

Tags: excel, vba

I recently found a macro to delete hidden names in a given workbook.

What I'd like to add to it is a pop up window that would first display how many names there are, and a yes no button for running it. Just to give the user an idea of how long the function will take to run if they choose to run it.

This is the code as is:

```
Dim RangeName As Name


On Error Resume Next
For Each RangeName In Names
    ActiveWorkbook.Names(RangeName.Name).Delete
Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim RangeName As Name
Dim answer As Integer
Dim str As String

On Error Resume Next

str = "Do you want to delete " & ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count & " names?"
answer = MsgBox(str, vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Message Box Title")

If answer Then
    For Each RangeName In Names
        ActiveWorkbook.Names(RangeName.Name).Delete
    Next
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried adding this as a new module to the workbook I'm using as a test but for some reason it's not coming up as a macro when I hit alt f8. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Have you added `Sub test()` and `End Sub`? Look at edited code.

Comment: That worked! Only thing is when I hit "No" The code started to run anyway.

Comment: Still seems to be running on no for some reason. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Sorry I'm terrible at this.

Comment: The code you don't want to executed after the **no answer** has to be placed after `else ` in my code. If It is outside of the `End if` It will be executed.